Cron Job on Directadmin executes after having been deleted
I deleted all cron Jobs from Directadmin dashboard but a previous old cron Job is still being activated by the Monibot crawler i.e
3.14.66.101 - - [23/Nov/2024:11:03:44 -0500] "GET /2024-2021/Community_Bible_Fellowship_Messages_2022/.index_cron.php HTTP/1.1" 404 3882 "-" "Monibot"
I want to delete this .index_cron.php script completely so that it does not get crawled and executed.
The script .index_cron.php does not appear anywhere in my domain files

It seems you forgot to ask a question. You can [edit] your question to clarify it
